# R: "Adding" 2 variables (columns) to create an aggregate variable (column)?

Tags: r, variables, aggregate, addition

This may be a strange request - I hope I am wording it correctly:
I have a dataset (df) and three variables (BELONG_1, GRPOR_14, ETHNIC10) that I want to "add" so as to get an aggregate variable (PsychIntegration) that can be run in a regression analysis - e.g. controlling for other variables such as gender, age etc.

BELONG_1: 1=Do not belong - 10=Do belong

GRPOR_14: 1=Not proud - 10=Very proud

ETHNIC10: 1=Not important - 4=Very important

The Cronbach Alpha for these three variables is 0.62

```
ID   BELONG_1   GRPOR_14    ETHNIC10    PsychIntegration
1      10          8           4              ??
2      3           4           2              ??
3      7           10          3              ??
4      1           1           1              ??
```

How exactly do I "add" (?) these variables to get PsychIntegration?

I hope that makes sense - thanks again!

Comment: So you desired output for ID 1 is 10 + 8 + 4 for PsychIntegration?

Comment: I believe so yes! I'm willing to try any approach at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the package `dplyr` (or package `tidyverse`). Assuming your data are stored in a data.frame named `df`

```r
df <- df %>%
  mutate(PsychIntegration = rowSums(select(., -ID)))
```

if you want to sum all rows. Use

```r
df <- df %>%
  mutate(PsychIntegration = BELONG_1 + GRPOR_14 + ETHNIC10)
```

if you just want to sum those three columns.

Using just `base` R one possibility is

```r
df$PsychIntegration <- df$BELONG_1 + df$GRPOR_14 + df$ETHNIC10
```

Comment: @SteffiGarrett So if you are satisfied, feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).